# Change android softkeyboard sample designs, button and background images

Tags: android

I'm building a custom keyboard by modifying the android softkeyboard sample from the SDK. I want to change the images of the buttons and the backgrounds but I can't figure out where those values are stored. Where are they stored or how can i change the image or simply color?

Answer (score 0):

in onClick method you need to change the Button's image, this way..

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==buttonName){
        buttonName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageName);
    }       
}
```

The keyboard background color can be changed in input.xml using `android:background`

Comment: Ok but how do i change the button image before it is clicked on? its default

Comment: I tried changing android:background for the input.xml and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the file `res/xml/qwerty.xml`.

You can check the documentation for [Keyboard](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html) and the [Keys](http://loper.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html). The last one defines what is shown on the keys (does not look like you can change the background though).

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the file

> res/layout/input.xml

A sample input.xml could look like this.

```
<com.example.keyboard.LatinKeyboardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/keyboardbackground"
    android:keyBackground="@drawable/samplekeybackground"
    android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/input_key_preview" 
    android:keyTextcolor="@android:color/black"/>
```

there are few more attributes that can be found in the [KeyboardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) documentation.