# How to set different background of keys for Android Custom Keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I am Working on Custom Keyboard Application

[image: This is background color of key when user select blue]

[image: If user select green this should be background color]

This is code for background color of `input.xml` in softkeyboard :-

```
     @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {


      Log.e("onStartInputView ","On StartInput View Called--");

      SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      String Backgroundcolour = preferences.getString("BackgroundColour","");

     Log.e("Brithnesss- -","----"+Backgroundcolour);

    if(Backgroundcolour.equalsIgnoreCase("black"))
    {

    this.mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.input, null);


    }else
    {
        this.mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.input1, null);
        //this.mInputView.setB
    }

    this.mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    this.mInputView.setKeyboard(this.mQwertyKeyboard);
    return this.mInputView;
}

 @Override public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
    super.onStartInputView(attribute, restarting);
    // Apply the selected keyboard to the input view.

    setInputView(onCreateInputView());

}
```

I am not getting how to set background image for specific key.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789997/how-to-change-background-color-of-key-for-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: i am not getting form this much properly can u please tell how i would set different color keys?

Comment: I need to set background for specific key background  instead of same key background image for whole keyboard. i need urgently

Comment: Hi @user...I had done with the colorful keys but the text in the keys are not visible..Can you please help me???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an example, there's a [small downloadable project](https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example) that creates a custom numeric keyboard. To the CustomKeyboardView class there or to your own custom keyboard class, add a method like the following. It overrides the onDraw() method and draws the background of the key defined with code 7 (in this case the "0") red and all the other keys blue.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for (Key key : keys) {            
        if (key.codes[0] == 7) {
            Log.e("KEY", "Drawing key with code " + key.codes[0]);
            Drawable dr = (Drawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_tint);
            dr.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
            dr.draw(canvas);

        } else {
            Drawable dr = (Drawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_tint);
            dr.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
            dr.draw(canvas);
        }            
    }
}
```

[image: tinted keys]

In this case, I didn't use 9-patch images, but just some simple 50% transparent square images and achieved an effect where the existing buttons are merely tinted with the colors I wanted. To get a more custom result, I could make my background drawables 9-patch images and do the following. Note that the two keys with icons don't render correctly because the icons aren't defined as 9-patch images and I didn't make any special effort to allow them to scale well for this example. I also didn't address the use of different images/effects for the various states for the keys; others have shown how to do that.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // super.onDraw(canvas);

    List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for (Key key : keys) {
        if (key.codes[0] == 7) {
            NinePatchDrawable npd
                = (NinePatchDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_key);
            npd.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
            npd.draw(canvas);

        } else {
            NinePatchDrawable npd
                = (NinePatchDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_key);
            npd.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
            npd.draw(canvas);
        }

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setTextSize(48);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        if (key.label != null) {
            canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x + (key.width / 2),
                            key.y + (key.height / 2), paint);
        } else {
            key.icon.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
            key.icon.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: replaced keys]

Comment: how to change the popup background programatically when long press on key of custom keyboardview?

Comment: The link provided in the answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MaihanNijat, It wasn't supposed to by itself; it's just a convenience that provides a fairly standard style custom keyboard. The code explicitly added in the answer demonstrates a simplistic change to that project (or the similar code provided in the official docs and other S/O posts) to answer the OP's question.

Comment: @scottt what do you use to close keyboard?

Comment: @ste9206     I had done with the colorful keys but the text in the keys are not visible..Can you please help me??

Answer (score 3):

I created a keyboard app in which I use the `KeyBackground` property in `KeyboardView`, like so:

```
<KeyboardView android:keyBackground="@drawable/buttonbgselector" .../>
```

To do this dynamically I use the following code:

```
@Override 
public View onCreateInputView() {
    mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input, null);
    mInputView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonbgselector);
    mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    mInputView.setKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
    return mInputView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple, you should make class `MyKeyboardView` and do some hack similar to this.

```
public class MyKeyboardView extends android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView {

    Context context;
    public MyKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Hippie.otf");
        paint.setTypeface(font);
        paint.setTextSize(40);

        List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        for(Key key: keys) { // int i = 0 ; switch(i) and implement your logic 

        if(key.pressed){
            NinePatchDrawable npd = (NinePatchDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.glow);
            npd.setBounds(key.x,key.y,key.x+key.width,key.y+key.height);
            npd.draw(canvas);
            if(key.label != null)
                canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x + (key.width/2), key.y + 25, paint);
        }else if(key.modifier){  // boolean that defines key is function key
            NinePatchDrawable npd = (NinePatchDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_keyboard_special);
            npd.setBounds(key.x,key.y,key.x+key.width,key.y+key.height);
            npd.draw(canvas);
            if(key.label != null)
                canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x + (key.width/2), key.y + 25, paint);
        }


        break;
    }
}
```