# Android custom numeric keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to add numeric keyboard like the one in vault application

> [image]

I don't know how to call it and how can I find in google ?

Comment: visit for an examplehttps://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example

Answer (score 68, accepted):

1. Use TableLayout to create the numeric keyboard layout.
2. Bind View.OnClickListener on each custom key view to response user input.
3. In responses, append or delete text to that password field which implements by EditText.You can use append() or setText() to control what will be filled in the password field.

I write a custom view for reusing in anywhere, here is the code:

`KeyboardView.java`

```
public class KeyboardView extends FrameLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText mPasswordField;

    public KeyboardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public KeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public KeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.keyboard, this);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        mPasswordField = $(R.id.password_field);
        $(R.id.t9_key_0).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_1).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_2).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_3).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_4).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_5).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_6).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_7).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_8).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_9).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_clear).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_backspace).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // handle number button click
        if (v.getTag() != null && "number_button".equals(v.getTag())) {
            mPasswordField.append(((TextView) v).getText());
            return;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.t9_key_clear: { // handle clear button
                mPasswordField.setText(null);
            }
            break;
            case R.id.t9_key_backspace: { // handle backspace button
                // delete one character
                Editable editable = mPasswordField.getText();
                int charCount = editable.length();
                if (charCount > 0) {
                    editable.delete(charCount - 1, charCount);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public String getInputText() {
        return mPasswordField.getText().toString();
    }

    protected <T extends View> T $(@IdRes int id) {
        return (T) super.findViewById(id);
    }
}
```

layout `keyboard.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:divider="@drawable/keyboard_divider"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end">

        <TableRow style="@style/keyboard_row">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_1"
                style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
                android:text="@string/number_one"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_2"
                style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
                android:text="@string/number_two"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_3"
                style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
                android:text="@string/number_three"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow style="@style/keyboard_row">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_4"
                style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
                android:text="@string/number_four"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_5"
                style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
                android:text="@string/number_five"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_6"
                style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
                android:text="@string/number_six"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow style="@style/keyboard_row">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_7"
                style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
                android:text="@string/number_seven"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_8"
                style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
                android:text="@string/number_eight"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_9"
                style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
                android:text="@string/number_nine"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow style="@style/keyboard_row">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_clear"
                style="@style/keyboard_button"
                android:text="@string/btn_clear"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_0"
                style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
                android:text="@string/number_zero"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_backspace"
                style="@style/keyboard_button"
                android:text="@string/btn_backspace"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`style.xml`

```
<style name="keyboard_row">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/keyboard_divider</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">beginning|middle|end</item>
</style>

<style name="keyboard_button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/keyboard_button_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
</style>

<style name="keyboard_number_button" parent="keyboard_button">
    <item name="android:tag">number_button</item>
</style>
```

drawable `keyboard_button_bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#dddddd"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

drawable `keyboard_divider.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#dddddd"/>
    <size
        android:width="1px"
        android:height="1px"/>
</shape>
```

`strings.xml`

```
<string name="number_zero">0</string>
<string name="number_one">1</string>
<string name="number_two">2</string>
<string name="number_three">3</string>
<string name="number_four">4</string>
<string name="number_five">5</string>
<string name="number_six">6</string>
<string name="number_seven">7</string>
<string name="number_eight">8</string>
<string name="number_nine">9</string>
<string name="btn_clear">Clear</string>
<string name="btn_backspace">Back</string>
```

Use the custom `KeyboardView` in your layout :

```
<com.xxx.yyy.KeyboardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

---

### Old answer:

The keyboard layout code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white_grey"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_1"
        style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
        android:text="@string/number_one"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_2"
        style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
        android:text="@string/number_two"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_3"
        style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
        android:text="@string/number_three"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_4"
        style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
        android:text="@string/number_four"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_5"
        style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
        android:text="@string/number_five"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_6"
        style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
        android:text="@string/number_six"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_7"
        style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
        android:text="@string/number_seven"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_8"
        style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
        android:text="@string/number_eight"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_9"
        style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
        android:text="@string/number_nine"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_clear"
        style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
        android:text="@string/anti_theft_keyboard_clear"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_0"
        style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
        android:text="@string/number_zero"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_backspace"
        style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name_for_anti_theft"
        android:src="@drawable/anti_theft_keyboard_backspace"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Each key style:

```
<style name="anti_theft_t9_key">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/anti_theft_t9_key_paddingTop</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/anti_theft_t9_key_paddingBottom</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/anti_theft_btn_blue_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
</style>
```

Responses of each key:

```
private EditText mEtPassword ;

private void setViews(){
    // find view references...
    // set OnClickListener to each key view...
}

private void onT9KeyClicked(int key) {
    switch (key) {
    case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_0:
        mEtPassword.append("0");
        break;
    case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_1:
        mEtPassword.append("1");
        break;
    case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_2:
        mEtPassword.append("2");
        break;
    case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_3:
        mEtPassword.append("3");
        break;
    case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_4:
        mEtPassword.append("4");
        break;
    case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_5:
        mEtPassword.append("5");
        break;
    case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_6:
        mEtPassword.append("6");
        break;
    case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_7:
        mEtPassword.append("7");
        break;
    case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_8:
        mEtPassword.append("8");
        break;
    case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_9:
        mEtPassword.append("9");
        break;
    case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_backspace: {
        // delete one character
        String passwordStr = mEtPassword.getText().toString();
        if (passwordStr.length() > 0) {
            String newPasswordStr = new StringBuilder(passwordStr)
                    .deleteCharAt(passwordStr.length() - 1).toString();
            mEtPassword.setText(newPasswordStr);
        }
    }
        break;
    case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_clear:
        // clear password field
        mEtPassword.setText(null);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you implement the strings,drawables,dimens and colors what I had not posted here?Or can you show some code snippet?I don't know what the problem you were facing.

Comment: Thanks.@AvatarQing, I got it now.

Comment: I'd like to propose a lazy suggestion. Set onClick(View v) to all of the keys. Then check if this key is text view (if v instanceof TextView) and to append the text just use mTextView.append(((TextView) v).getText());
This way you don't need to write the same line multiple times.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thanks @AvatarQing

Comment: Awesome answer! How do I implement this so that I can use it for multiple activities?

Comment: @NiiLaryea Create a new custom view, inflate layout from xml to the new view in constructor, then find and set each view, add some public methods   to expose to external invoke which can get some useful data. Finally reuse this view in anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean a custom view that extends the `TableLayout`?

Comment: @NiiLaryea I write a custom view for you, please check the updated answer.

Comment: How can we access the password_field textview in SomeActivity.java which has layout file SomeLayout.xml containing KeyboardView? I just want to get the number entered by keyboard and use it further.

Comment: @ArewegoodQ I have defined a method named `getInputText()` which return the text of password field. Or you can define your own method which return the password_field TextView instance.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Copied the code 1:1 and edited my manifest, but it never shows up. also android studio tells me that I am not allowed to put this into my manifest.

Comment: Best answer ever! Thank you!

Comment: More helpful answer.

Comment: How do you bind a hardware keyboard number input with this. So that if we tap a number key it will start showing on the edittextview

Answer (score -1):

There is an open source library solving your exact problem on github: [clamnumpad](https://github.com/nightcrawler-/clamnumpad/packages/152923)

Answer (score -2):

You can set inputType of the EditText to **number** for this.

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

And if you want to set password field as well, use **numberPassword**

Comment: Yes,But I want to customize the look of keyboard.

Comment: For that, you will need to write your own keyboard layout as AvatarQing has suggested in answer. Write drawables for colors, backgrounds as you like.  Inflate the layout and set it to the KeyboardView.

Please refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224520/how-to-set-different-background-of-keys-for-android-custom-keyboard).  Hope this helps.  Let me know if you need details.

Comment: not showing as per question asked, opens default numeric keypad