# How to implement the google wallet keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-pay

I want to implement the keyboard of google wallet. Anyone know how to do that. The keyboard is on the page. Not the system default keyboard. Thank you[image] Or how can I draw a keyboard?

this Link [Android custom numeric keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872150/android-custom-numeric-keyboard) will help you figure this problem

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Where specifically are you running into difficulty implementing this?

Comment: I know how to implement the paring, but use the default keyboard. I do not know how to draw the keyboard? Is this keyboard use XML draw it , or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily see how Google implemented the keyboard by downloading the [Google Wallet APK](http://www.apk4fun.com/apk/7185/) (or by rooting your phone and pulling the APK off) and unpacking/decompiling it with your tool of choice (e.g. [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler), [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/), [JD](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui), etc.).  I can only speculate, but I think they did this to minimize the possibility of a third-party keyboard app logging the input, and so that they can "shred" the PIN in memory as soon as it has been used.

The keypad is just a bunch of buttons laid out as a table/grid, and the buttons are customized to have the subscript effect (i.e. `2ABC`) using [SpannableStrings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

After decompiling, you can find what you're interested in by looking at the `com.google.android.apps.wallet.pin` package, specifically the `PinButton` class.  Also, look at the `/res/layout/pin_view.xml` layout and its includes (`pin_fields.xml` and `pin_pad.xml`).