# Unable to access views inside an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I copied the entire code from here

[Android custom numeric keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872150/android-custom-numeric-keyboard)

and used it inside an `AlertDialog`. Now when I debug the application, the `onClick()` isn't getting invoked.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setView(R.layout.keypad_layout);
                builder.setCancelable(false).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Modify", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });
                builder.create().show();\
```

The alert dialog is showing and positive and negative buttons work only problem is that I cannot access the views inside the layout

Comment: I think it is invoked at all, but debugger does not stop at empty functions. So try to insert a command like String s = "test";

Comment: the onClick()  method inside the KeyboardView class and not the onClick of the AlertDialog

Comment: What does "I cannot access the views inside the layout" mean, specifically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, `AlertDialog` returns a `view`

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
mPasswordField = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.password_field);
```

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inflate the layout to a View instance first, then you can set the OnClickListeners for the keys:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.keypad_layout, null);
builder.setView(mView);

final TextView key8 = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.t9_key_8);
key8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // do something
            }
        });
```

repeat that what I have done for key8 with the other keys