# What is the meaning of a dollar sign before an Android resource id

Tags: java, android

In the accepted answer of the following post([Android custom numeric keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872150/android-custom-numeric-keyboard/21873135)) I found a syntax that I don't understand:

```
$(R.id.t9_key_0).setOnClickListener(this);
```

What does the dollar sign mean in front? Is it specifically related to Android resource ids or is more a general Java syntax? Search engine results didn't show any suitable results.

Comment: Are they trying to make jQuery in Java? o.O

Comment: jQuery is good. you should definitely try jQuery.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's a method call where the method name is `$`. The method is defined as follows in the code you linked:

```
protected <T extends View> T $(@IdRes int id) {
    return (T) super.findViewById(id);
}
```

The method is a helper that removes the need to cast the return type of `findViewById()`. [It's no longer needed as of Android O as the platform `findViewById()` uses generics to do the same.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#fvbi-signature)

The name `$` is likely inspired by [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787342/why-does-jquery-have-dollar-signs-everywhere).

Answer (score 1):

Earlier days we know we needed to cast every return type of `findViewById()` method. Like

usual way

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

This guy way

```
TextView textView = $(R.id.textView);
```

**He ignored typecasting by his generic method.**

So the guy used **[Java generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)**  to ignore type casting all the `findViewById();`. If you don't understand Generics, please read **[Why to use generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)**.

```
protected <T extends View> T $(@IdRes int id) {
    return (T) super.findViewById(id);
}
```

So now he doesn't need to type cast

```
TextView textView = $(R.id.textView);
```

**Explanation of this method.**

- He created a method which accept resource id. So he can pass an Id.
- He annotated this parameter by **`@IdRes`** so that Android Studio only allow resource ids in this parameter.
- Then he called super class method `findViewById` which returns View.
- He returned **`<T extends View>`**  from method, so you will always have View object in return type.

#### Important

Now you don't need to make your generic methods. Because Android itself has changed his method. See **[Android Oreo Changes for `findViewById()`](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#fvbi-signature).**

> All instances of the findViewById() method now return 
>   T instead of View.

Now you also can do same like that guy without typecasting

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
```