# How to set attribute colors on a custom keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-custom-keyboard

I'm trying to make my custom keyboard to change his colors according to the **current theme** in project, but it fails, this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:keyBackground = "@drawable/keybackground"
        android:keyTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:background="?attr/android:colorBackground"
        android:keyTextSize="22sp"/>
```

When I put regular colors everything works fine! How can I do it flexible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set different background of keys for Android Custom Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224520/how-to-set-different-background-of-keys-for-android-custom-keyboard)

Comment: no my qoustion is completely different! please read before marking it as duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for but you could try using the res-auto namespace:

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    custom:keyBackground = "@drawable/keybackground"
    custom:keyTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:background="?attr/android:colorBackground"
    custom:keyTextSize="22sp"/>
```

If you are looking for changing it dynamically while the app is running I think the linked answer is the way to go. Things that should be changed dynamically is preferably done in code while static design preferably is done in xml.