# How to change the idiom of the keyboard using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, keyboard, cultureinfo, culture

I have a Xamarin forms App (iOS, Android & UWP) and, on the settings of my App, the user can choose the language they want to use in the app.

The App is already able to "translate" the texts, date format, and number format, but **I don't know how to change the keyboard's idiom.**

I already tried the methods below but it didn't work

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =  new CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

**Use case:**

The user is from German, and he uses Deutsch as a default language on his device. However,  he defined on the App settings (inside my App) the English Language.

When the user needs to input a text in an Edit Text (Editor or Entry), the keyboard layout needs to be English instead of Deutsch.

Is it possible with Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research I did not find any way to switch between language keyboards in a simple manner, by the other hand [I found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787385/custom-keyboard-in-xamarin-forms#answer) in order to create your own custom keyboard with the language you wish with `PageRenderer`.

Comment: Thanks, @manuelbr98. But it will be complicated to create a bunch of custom keyboards for each language.

Comment: Sorry @Romer but I did not find any other workaround