# How to add send button in keyboard in editor rather than return type key of keyboard in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have editor and I don't have send button in design, as I am using editor default return type key is enter and as I know by replacing return type key to done I am able to send text but unable to enter so I want both enter as well as send action on keyboard. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Keyboard in Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787385/custom-keyboard-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

We can't only add a custom button on the default keyboard. We need to customize the keyboard to achieve that.

You could follow this thread to create your keyboard:[Custom Keyboard in Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787385/custom-keyboard-in-xamarin-forms)

There is an sample in this link, you could refer to his customrenderer ： https://github.com/Eren-Shen/CustomKeyboardDemo/tree/master/CustomKeyboardDemo/CustomKeyboardDemo.iOS