# Is it possible to customize the keys shown on a .net Maui keyboard?

Tags: maui

My ideal solution would be to add the "/" and "X" keys to the numeric keyboard (this is for a bowling scoring app). Possible?

This would be for both Android and iOS.

I've only seen references to the standard keyboard types (chat, email, numeric, etc.).

Comment: google `xamarin forms custom keyboard`. Should be similar for Maui.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the keyboard in .Net MAUI.

If you want to implement simple customizations such as hinting at keyboard use and capitalizations are built in. You can refer to https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/blob/main/docs/user-interface/controls/entry.md#customize-the-keyboard .

If you want to implement completely customizing keyboard, you can use essentially the same techniques you use in Xamarin to do so as in Maui. It's because that the customization is not Xamarin specific behavior but comes from the underlying Android API.

**Update:**

For more information about customizing the keyboard in xamarin forms, you can check the following links:

[Custom Keyboard in Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787385/custom-keyboard-in-xamarin-forms)  and [Custom Keyboard In Xamarin.iOS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-keyboard-in-xamarin-ios/#:%7E:text=Here%20are%20the%20steps%20to%20create%20a%20custom,Extension%20--%3E%20Custom%20Keyboard%20Extension%20and%20click%20Next.)

In maui, you can read more about [handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-7.0) to custom your view.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking to add a few characters to the numeric keyboard, not set flags for a standard implementation. I need this for iOS and Android. The only thing I've found so far is an iOS keyboard extension project type - and I have no idea yet if it is even compatible with Maui (or what I will be able to do with this extension).

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check the updated part.