# Custom Android keyboard with Material Design Style

Tags: android, material-design, custom-keyboard

I have recently updated my app to implement Material Design. To make the app backwards compatible, I changed my appBaseTheme from "Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar". However, I have a custom keyboard that keeps popping up in the old holo theme.

I think I have to use a style called "Widget.Material.Light.KeyboardView", but I get the message:

> Error: Resource is not public

when I try to use it in the theme attribute of my keyboardView.
All I want is for my keyboard to look similar to the new Lollipop keyboard. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I would love to see how you got Material Design working, my keyboard still looks like it's from Gingerbread.

Comment: I actually found what we were looking for. I'm going to go ahead and flag this as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change background color of key for android soft keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789997/how-to-change-background-color-of-key-for-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

I somehow also missed this answer, but this should cover what you're trying to do. Setting a flat color to the keys or the background will give it a very Material look, depending on the color palette you choose.

[How to change background color of key for android soft keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789997/how-to-change-background-color-of-key-for-android-soft-keyboard)